# Accessing Eloquent Relationship Automatically when loaded

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am working on  a project which requires me to get all the list of all information from a table --*Just like in  a blog*, i used the `all()` method to do this but when i try to get the method i declared in my Model i get an error, saying

> the collection instance does not exists

But when i use The 
`Model::find($id)->relationship()->name;`

it works fine. Is there any way to load all relationship with the `all()` function in laravel.

Thanks for your help..

Comment: if found this link you can use it  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/get-all-model-relationships

Comment: You can load relationships on the query with `$model = Model::with(["relationship", "other", ...])->find($id);`; they'll then be available via `$model->relationship->first()->name` or `$model->other->name`, based on whether or not it's a one-to-one or one-to-many, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform `Model::find($id)->relationship();` you are actually accesing to the [Dynamic relationships Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

You need to convert it into a collection using `Model::find($id)->relationship()->get();`

Then you can perform any [collection method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-collections#available-methods) to get the result you want. After doing this you can access to its attributes like this:

```
$model_varible = Model::find($id)->relationship()->get();
$model_variable = $model_variable->find($id)->name;
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use relationship without brackets to access the model:

```
Model::find($id)->relationship->name;
```

And use "with()" to populate the relationships:

```
Model::where('published', 1)->with('relationship')
```

Comment: I actually got that part working, but the problem is i need the relationships to be loaded with the collection instance, because i am am pulling all the information in the table not getting specific row

Comment: with() should accomplish this: $models = Model::with('relationship')->all(). Then you can call $models->first()->relationship->name

Comment: Or you can use "protected $with = ['relationship'];" it you Model class and the model will always be loaded with the relationship.